# How can I remove the music bar in iMovie 10.0.3?

Tags: music, imovie

I last used iMovie 3 months ago, but now it's totally different.  I've figured out some things, but under the audio track there is now space for a music track, which I'm not using, and I can't see how to hide it.  It takes up so much room that I can't see enough of my clip to work on.  Is there any way to hide the music track if I'm not adding music?

Answer (score 1):

*I presume you're referring to this bar at the bottom of the timeline:*

[image]

At the time of writing (iMovie 10.0.4) this bar can not be hidden from the timeline. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/imovie.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can do without the audio waveforms always showing, in the timeline settings unchecking 'Audio: [✔] Show Waveforms' --> 'Audio: [ ] Show Waveforms' will open up a lot of the vertical screen real-estate in the timeline.